# Android with Aftek AMF. Why am I getting no response from my server even after I compile the code with no errors and the app loads fine?

Tags: android, amf

I have followed the Aftek example and the app loads, I enter in a name and password click the button to send, but get nothing in return. No errors or anything to go on, I apologize for my lack of knowledge on this subject up front. If anyone has any experience with Aftek's AMF library, I would be so thankful for your input.

```
package com.ryan.etrak2;

import com.al.amf.channels.AMFChannel;
import com.al.amf.events.ErrorEvent;
import com.al.amf.events.ResultEvent;
import com.al.amf.remoting.RemoteListener;
import com.al.amf.remoting.RemoteObject;
import flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
implements OnClickListener, RemoteListener 
{
public ArrayCollection resultarr;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) 
{
System.out.println(" button clicked");
EditText username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

try
{
AMFChannel channel = new AMFChannel("http://192.168.0.109/8084/default/servlet/AMFgateway", this);
    RemoteObject remoteObject = channel.getRemoteObject("messageBO");

    remoteObject.addRemoteListener(this);
    Object[] params = new Object[]{};
            RemoteObject client = null;
    client.call("login", params);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

// Invoked on successful remote procedure call.
public void onResult(ResultEvent resultEvent)
{
System.out.println("success:" + resultEvent.getData());
}

// Invoked on remote procedure call failure.   
public void onError(ErrorEvent errorEvent)
{
System.out.println("Error occured:" + errorEvent.getData());
}
}
```

Comment: Where did you find the download for Aftek library?